# Having trouble with TimeSpan in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, timespan

In VB.net I have been learning through Murach's Visual Basic 2010. When learning how to deal with time and strings I came across a problem with timespan.

I need to take 2 dates and find the number of days between them.

so I declared my variables.

```
Dim currentDay As Date
Dim futureDate As Date
Dim timespan As TimeSpan = currentDay.Subtract(futureDate)
Dim strMsgText As String
Dim daysUntilDue = timespan.Days
```

then I set formats for currentDay and futureDate

```
currentDay = Convert.ToDateTime(Now)
futureDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFutureDate.Text) 'input from user
```

then I set the data I need displayed

```
 strMsgText = "Current Date: " & currentDay.ToShortDateString() _
            & "Future Date: " & futureDate.ToShortDateString() _
            & "Days Util Due " & daysUntilDue
```

next I provided data validation

```
If IsDate(txtFutureDate.Text) Then
   futureDate = CDate(txtFutureDate.Text)
End If
```

finally I display the data

```
MessageBox.Show(strMsgText)
```

I get no errors in syntax or errors from the vb ide
however, when it calculates the dates it gives me this in the message box

ex.

```
Current Date: 3/30/2013

Future Date: 12/26/2013

 Days Until Due: 0
```

I have tried to flip the dates in the calculation

ex. instead of `currentDay.Subtract(futureDate)` I set it as `futureDate.Subtract(currentDay)` just to see if it would give me a different result. But, alas, it still comes out to be 0.

I know I am doing something wrong for this to be the result but I cannot find out what it is with the IDE/Compiler not giving me any errors and the book not giving me any advice or know how on how to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that at the time you are setting the timespan value `currentDay` and `futureDate` have not been initialized and have the default value for a `DateTime`. The subtraction of these will always be a 0 `TimeSpan`.

Set `timespan` *after* you have set these two dates.

```
Dim currentDay As Date
Dim futureDate As Date
Dim strMsgText As String

currentDay = Convert.ToDateTime(Now)
futureDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFutureDate.Text) 'input from user

Dim timespan As TimeSpan = currentDay.Subtract(futureDate)
Dim daysUntilDue = timespan.Days
```

Comment: alrighty thank you.    put the code in with timespan and daysUntilDue in after currentDay and futureDate are assigned values and reversed my equation to futureDate.Subtrace(currentDay). And Kabam it works great. Knew it had to be a logic error i'm not the brightest crayon in the box

Comment: @thewaytonever - No problem. Hope you understood where you went wrong and why this is the answer.

Comment: @thewaytonever - We all started somewhere. Things are not obvious or natural when it comes to programming.

Comment: absolutely  visual basic needs to have everything arranged in order of execution in order for it to run the program line by line.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to check if the user has entered a valid date, you can use DateTime.TryParse to determine that:

```
Dim currentDay As Date = DateTime.Now
Dim futureDate As Date
Dim strMsgText As String
Dim daysUntilDue As Integer

currentDay = DateTime.Now

Dim ci As New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

' check if a parseable date has been entered before doing the calculation
If DateTime.TryParse(txtFutureDate.Text, ci, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, futureDate) Then
    daysUntilDue = (futureDate - currentDay).Days
    strMsgText = "Current Date: " & currentDay.ToShortDateString() & " Future Date: " & futureDate.ToShortDateString() & " Days Until Due " & daysUntilDue.ToString
Else
    strMsgText = "I could not understand the future date as entered."
End If

MessageBox.Show(strMsgText)
```